# Wave scattering by crystals

Tags: solid-state-physics, diffraction, crystals

The structure factor is defined as (assuming orthogonal axes):

$$S_{(hkl)} = \sum_{j \in \mathcal{U}} f_j \exp\{2\pi i (hx_j+ky_j+lz_j)\},$$

where $\mathcal{U}$ is a unit cell of the lattice and the sum is over *all* atoms in the unit cell. However in calculations I see that people often use only the basis vectors of the atoms in a unit cell and call this also $S_{(hkl)}$. My question is: how can we get away with this?

Comment: I don't understand your question: $x_i, y_i, z_i$ are the coordinates of the $i$-th atom with respect to the unit cell basis vectors (the so-called fractional coordinates).

Comment: Yes, $x_j,y_j,z_j$ are the coordinates of the $j$-th atom in a unit cell with respect to the orthogonal basis for clarification. The question is why people only sum over the atoms described in the basis instead of all the atoms in the unit cell.

Comment: The original sum is over all the atoms but it can be rearranged as a sum over all the unit cells: the contribution of each unit cell factors out, and you are left with the product of $S_{(hkl)}$ with 3 Laue functions, one for each unit cell axis.

Comment: @frapadingue that looks like an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total structure factor of the crystal is the sum over all the atoms,

$$S(\mathbf{h}) = \sum_a f_a \exp{2i\pi\mathbf{h} \cdot \mathbf{r}_a}$$

where $\mathbf{h}=(h,k,l)$ is the triplet of Miller indices and $\mathbf{r}_a$ is the triplet of coordinates of the atom $a$. The dot is a scalar product. But then we can write $\mathbf{r}_a = \mathbf{n} + \mathbf{u}_a$ where $\mathbf{n}$ is a triplet of integers that is the position of the centre of the unit cell $U_{\mathbf{n}}$ the atom $a$ belongs to, and $\mathbf{u}_a$ is the position of $a$ with respect to that centre. I take the centre here but any point of the unit cell would do, even vertices. So now, we can rewrite $S$ as a double-sum over all unit cells, and within each of them over the atoms.

$$S(\mathbf{h}) = \sum_{\mathbf{n}}\sum_{a\in U_{\mathbf{n}}}f_a \exp{2i\pi\,\mathbf{h} \cdot (\mathbf{n} + \mathbf{u}_a}) = \left(\underbrace{\sum_{\mathbf{n}} \exp{2i\pi\,\mathbf{h} \cdot \mathbf{n}}}_{\text{Laue function}\ L(\mathbf{h})}\right)\left(\sum_{a\in U_{\mathbf{n}}}f_a \exp{2i\pi\,\mathbf{h} \cdot \mathbf{u}_a}\right)$$

With $2N_1+1$, $2N_2+1$, and $2N_3+1$ unit cells in each direction, the Laue function reads

$$L(\mathbf{h}) = \left(\sum_{n_1=-N_1}^{N_1}\exp(2i\pi n_1h)\right)\left(\sum_{n_2=-N_2}^{N_2}\exp(2i\pi n_2k)\right)\left(\sum_{n_3=-N_3}^{N_3}\exp(2i\pi n_3l) \right)$$

i.e. the product of three elementary Laue functions. Each of them will read like

$$\frac{\sin{2\pi Nh}}{\sin{2\pi h}}.$$

For large $N$, this function is 0 everywhere except for integer $h$. So we can drop that factor and we are left with the term you wondered about.

Comment: The $a$ in the summation in the second equation is over the atoms in a unit cell. My problem is that most books just sum over only the atoms that define the basis instead of all $a \in U_n$. Is this due to the fact that one can always write $S(\mathbf{h})$ as $S_{\mathrm{basis}} \times S_{\mathrm{lattice}}$ and since the diffraction pattern (zero or non-zero) is only determined by $S_{\mathrm{basis}}$ we only care about that factor?

Comment: What do you mean by "the atoms that define the basis"?

Comment: Given the primitive unit cell of a simple cubic lattice you can define a basis or motif. These are the coordinates of *some* atoms in that unit cell that under translational symmetry of the lattice gives us the whole periodic crystal. My problem is that in the given definition we sum over all atoms in the unit cell instead of those atoms that define the basis whereas all examples I see only sum over these ‘basis atoms’

Comment: You mean if the crystal has a symmetry? For example, half the cubic unit cell can be deduced from the other half by a mirror…

Comment: I already solved the issue. It is due to the fact that for example an atom on the corner counts for only 1/8.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote then: symmetry. Your atom is on a symmetry axis or plane. I can update my answer with the way it is done in most crystallographic software if you wish. But you said you solved it already… Well, could be useful for others!

Comment: If you like for other people it indeed may useful!